# Solidworks 2014 body partition

Tags: solidworks

I have a body (cylinder) in Solidworks 2014, how do I dissect this body in two parts using middle plane?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [Split](http://help.solidworks.com/2013/English/SolidWorks/sldworks/c_Splitting_Parts_and_Saving_Bodies.htm) feature  to create multiple parts from an existing part.

Comment: I did that, thank you very much, but if I create two parts after split, I save them into parts and then create assembly from them, I get external references. How do I get rid of external references to original file?

Answer (score 3):

In SolidWorks, you can right click in the Feature Manager Tree, and choose, View External References.  In the dialog, you can choose Lock to turn them off for the time being (allowing you to turn them on again later) or Break to permanently delete them.  You cannot however, re-establish broken external references without re-creating them.

This will still preserve the icons next to the features with external references

```
-> = In Context External Reference
->? = Out of Context External Reference
->* = Locked External Reference
->x = Broken External Reference.
```

If you're looking at how to do this in code, I would need to wait until I'm in front of my machine with SW to check.